# Angular + Bootstrap Accordion, Browser Back button action and opening the corresponding item

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-bootstrap

I have implemented `Bootstrap accordion(3.*.*)` using `Angular JS (1.2.*)`. Here I have used ui-router to load template when click each item in accordion. its working fine.

But I am getting the following error whenever click any item

```
Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression '$state.includes('customers')' used with directive 'accordionGroup' is non-assignable!
```

I am getting the error in the below line. I have checked the following condition for opening the corresponding item whenever user click browser back button. How can i fix this?

```
is-open="$state.includes('customers')"
```

Also, I have checked the above condition in each item for 2 times. one for `is-open`. Another one for changing `glyphicon` in the right corner of each item. How can i reduce the code for this lengthy checking?

I want to fix the above issue inside view itself. I don't want to fix this from controller.

Here is a [fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/JuPEsu?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by assigning the active class in separate variable using `ng-init`

Working [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RbqCGd?p=preview)

```
ng-init="customersAccordionActive=$state.includes('customers');"

is-open="customersAccordionActive"
```